# 'xeyes' : how to start 'undecorated' : and at boot?

Tags: boot, xorg

It's fun to run 'xeyes' on Raspbian - because of the big Raspberry in the middle of the desktop.

But by default if you just type 'xeyes' in a terminal : the eyes come up with extra 'decorations' on them, like this:

[image: decorated eyes]

You can switch off the decorations by clicking on the top-bar of the xeyes window, so they end up looking like this (and the it looks like the Raspberry is watching your every (mouse) move !)

[image]

So how can I :

a) Make them show up 'undecorated' by default
and
b) Have them launch when I start my desktop ?

BTW: you need to install 'xeyes' on Raspbian - they are not there by default.
I used :

```
sudo apt-get install x11-apps
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow, `xeyes`.  Been a while since I've seen that.  Have you checked out `xsnow`, lol? (Actually I think you have to compile that from source now, no one even distributes it).

This isn't really an answer to A or B but it is an answer to C) How to make sure it ends up in the right place when undecorated.

For an answer to B, have a look into [lxde autostart](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=LXDE+autostart), which there will be many examples of here and elsewhere online.

For an answer to A, I think LXDE uses openbox as the window manager and you might be able to configure that way, [see e.g. here](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=31566).

Being a traditional X app it (ostensibly) [obeys the `--geometry` setting](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xeyes.1.html).  That man page doesn't explain it but the setting is always of the form `widthxheight+horizontal+vertical`, e.g., `5x10+50+25` but you can leave the w x h out, e.g., just `+50+25`. It's in pixels, so will take a few minutes playing around.

I wrote "ostensibly" because the window manager could screw with it -- that's what's adding those decorations.  But probably not. There *may* be a way to tell LXDE to not used them for xeyes in particular, I dunno.  As mentioned, I'd check and see if openbox is in use (`ls -A | grep openbox`) and investigate that.

Once you get the geometry worked out you can actually include it in a config file called `/etc/X11/Xresources` (I think this still exists by default), add something like:

```
xeyes*geometry +100+50
```

If it doesn't work source it from your `.xinit` or similar.  But it may be easier for you to just include the command line invocation in an LXDE start-up thing, or a short hand script / shell function.

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` or `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`

Set

```
<decor>no</decor>
```

for the xeyes app.

EDIT:
That file didn't work so I just added some lines after the big application example comment in file that was there.
    ~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml

This puts the eyes in the center:

```
pi@raspberrypi2 ~ $ cd .config/openbox/
pi@raspberrypi2 ~/.config/openbox $ tail lxde-pi-rc.xml 
-->
  <application name="xeyes">
   <position force="yes">
      <x>center</x>
      <y>center</y>
    </position>
    <decor>no</decor>
  </application>
</applications>
</openbox_config>
pi@raspberrypi2 ~/.config/openbox $
```

Answer (score 1):

In Raspbian, there is also tuxeyes if you just want to install one app and not all the X11 apps.  Great for checking if X11 Forwarding is working :)

```
sudo apt install tuxeyes
```