# Xinit/matchbox remove border

Tags: kiosk

I have a script to run a python/GTK webbrowser on my raspberry pi.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
matchbox-windows-manager &
Xorg -nocursor
X -nocursor
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset s noblank
python display.py (this is the browser)
```

I'm looking for a way to remove the border and 'X' and make it full screen.

I have tried adding the `-use_titlebar no;` however I can't find in what context to use it.

Comment: If you only want to run one app you don't need a window manager, which will guarantee you won't have a titlebar or borders.  You'll also have no way to resize it, so you'll have to make sure the application can set its own geometry.

Comment: you should put this as an answer. And Thanks, didn't realise i didn't need a window manager to create a window.

Comment: I just submitted an edit to your question which also fixes the typo `machbox-windows-manager` to `matchbox-windows-manager` (note the missing "t"). Is there a chance that this typo caused the window manager to not start at all and hence not made the application full-screen?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with the Matchbox Window Manager, but I always use the [Ratpoison Window Manager](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/) ([package "ratpoison" in Raspbian/Debian/Ubuntu](https://packages.debian.org/stable/ratpoison)) for such purposes.

Ratpoison makes any window full-screen by default and only adds a 1 pixel border by default -- but it can be configured to have no border at all. Putting `border 0` into `~/.ratpoisonrc` should suffice for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default manager, Openbox, the boarder is part of what they call decorations. I wrote some XML to remove the decorations from xeyes here:

['xeyes' : how to start 'undecorated' : and at boot?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43993/xeyes-how-to-start-undecorated-and-at-boot/44007#44007)